# django-tastypie exclude field if request has filter

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a Resource with field `some_field`.

I need to exclude the the field in the response when I make request with a GET-parameter `some_get_param`.

If I remove it in the dehydrate method, I will have done more work on the calculation of the value of this field than necessary. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in the field definition `attribute=None` instead of string naming, and then manually dehydrating field in `full_dehydrate` method or deleting this field from response depending on `bundle.request.GET.get('param', None)` value.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a normal field, then there really won't be much of an overhead. The bigger overhead is (arguably) in the payload to the server, ie not having the field in the response might already be an improvement.

You could also add the field to the `excludes` list as [in the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#fetching-data).

Finally, if that still doesn't work for you, you could create a custom endpoint using `override_urls`. For a simple field exclusion this is overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote my working solution below.